# ReactJS How to pass child component values to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below codes

**chat.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/Chat.css';
import Web from '../services/Web';

class Chat extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        msg:''
    };
    this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
 }

 sendMessage () {
    this.props.updatecommentText(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.index);
    this.setState({ msg: '' });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="Chat-container">
      <div className="Chat-row">
        <div className="Chat-column">
          <div className="Chat-card">
            <div className="Chat-body">
               <div className="Chat-title">React Based Chatbot</div>
               <div className="Chat-messages">
                 { this.props.children } 
           </div>
           </div>
            <div className="Chat-footer">
                  <textarea className="Chat-input" ref="newText"></textarea>
                  <button className="Chat-submit" onClick={this.sendMessage} defaultValue={ this.props.children }>Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
}


export default Chat;
```

**Web.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Chat from '../components/Chat';

class Web extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         messages:["Hi, How can I help you ?"
         ]
      };
      this.sendtobot = this.sendtobot.bind(this);
  }

  sendtobot(newText, i){
     var arr = this.state.messages
     arr.push(newText)
     this.setState({messages: arr})
  }

  eachMessage(message, i){
        return (<Chat key={i} index={i} updatecommentText={ this.sendtobot.bind(this) }>{ message }</Chat>);
  }

  render(){
     return(
       <div>
         {this.state.messages.map(this.eachMessage.bind(this))}
       </div>
     )
  }

}

export default Web;
```

I wanted to take the input from the **Chat.js** and send it to **Web.js** and push that value to array messages and then again render that array in the `this.props.children` in **Chat.js**

But, while running the code, I am getting an error `this.props.updatecommentText is not a function.`
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: as pointed by @bamse below, this seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/52zr6y73xn It does have some weird code, but functionally it is working. Are you sure you have not left out something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have bind `this.sendtobot` twice. It should be only in the constructor.
like this

```
eachMessage(message, i){
        return (
          <Chat key={i} index={i} updatecommentText={this.sendtobot}>
           { message }
           </Chat>
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/42p835oyw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fweb.js) is a sandbox with your code.

I'm not sure it works as you would expect, but it works without errors.

Comment: Yes...I just saw that

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit 610v6oo5qz]

By changing this 3 functions in Web component, it starting to look like a chat with only one textarea

```
  sendtobot(newText, i) {
    this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, newText] })
  }

  eachMessage(message, i) {
    return (<p>{message}</p>);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.messages.map(this.eachMessage.bind(this))}
        <Chat updatecommentText={this.sendtobot}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: It worked...but its coming outside of that chat window

Answer (score -1):

You can pass child's component state to parent component using redux also as global state.

Comment: Can you please explain it or give an example for the same

Comment: This seems like a bad advice. Why should one have to pass using URL params or introduce redux to do that? Does react provide no way to do so?

Comment: So doesn't react has such feature to implement?